# Move Ubuntu from an SSD to a partition on another SSD

Tags: dual-boot, ssd

I currently have a dual boot situation with two SSDs. Number 1 has Ubuntu on it, number 2 Windows 10.
I want to move Ubuntu to a new partition on the second SSD as it has about 500 GB of free space.
How can I create the partition on the second SSD and move Ubuntu to it?

**To be clear:**

*Currently:*

SSD 1: Ubuntu (120 GB)

SSD 2: Windows 10 (445 GB) + 465 GB free space

*Future:*

SSD 2: Windows 10 + Ubuntu

(no SSD 1)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can google how to separate home to a new partition.  Will leave Ubuntu / partition on SSD1, but have /home on second partition of SSD2.  /home is where most of your data is, and depending on the person have need of more space.  Will also give you about 30GBs extra for data that / partition usually takes/needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can install ubuntu onto the 2nd SSD so you'll get to set dual booting option, afterward, using clonezilla or similar cloning tool, clone ubuntu file system partition from SSD1 into ubuntu filesystem partition in SSD2.

you just need to make sure you clone it into the correct partition on SSD2, so I advice create a drive image of your SSD2 with clonezilla before trying... so if you make a mistake, you can restore it.

This is just how I would do it, so I hope other people can provide a less complicated and safer option.

Comment: Instead of Clonezilla you can use GParted to copy-paste the Ubuntu system partition to the new location. I did it a little differently.

Answer (score 0):

### Move Ubuntu to Windows Disk

**This is what I did**

- Use Windows to create free space on disk
- Boot Computer with Live Ubuntu USB
- Use GParted to copy-paste Ubuntu from it's disk to the new space.
- You can run `sudo update-grub` on the old Ubuntu disk to add the new Ubuntu to it, or you can use a USB with GRUB installed on it, to boot the new Ubuntu or you can install GRUB to the Windows/Ubuntu disk to overwrite the Windows bootloader.

If you are using the same bootloader to boot Windows and Ubuntu, both OS must be installed in the same BIOS/UEFI mode. If you are already using GRUB installed on the Windows disk then you only need to update GRUB.